# Access VBA - How to use User Defined Function in SQL string?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to create a Parameter Query in Access 2007 VBA that takes two input parameters from user forms and also returns a derived field value based on the public function RESULT I have written elsewhere in the code. The function determines the value of a calculated "Result" field which is derived from the values of 4 fields in the underlying table, [HomeTeam],[AwayTeam],[HomeGoals],[AwayGoals].

If I debug the code through the immediate window and paste the SQL string into the Access SQL window the query runs perfectly but will not run from VBA. The error generated is:

"Run-time error 3141.  The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."

I do not want to run the query directly in Access as the Parameter [season] is a table variable.

Does anybody know if and how I can call a user defined function in VBA within a SQL string?
I am unsure if this is just a syntax problem.

**Code:**

```
Sub sqlSeason()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim season As String
Dim team As String
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

DoCmd.Close acQuery, "qrySeason"

db.QueryDefs.Delete "qrySeason"

season = [Forms]![frmSeason]![comboSeason]

strSQL = "PARAMETERS [Forms]![frmClubProfile]![comboTeam] Text (255), [Forms]![frmSeason]![comboSeason] Text (255) ;" & _
"SELECT [Date], [HomeTeam], [AwayTeam], [HomeGoals], [AwayGoals], Result([HomeTeam], [AwayTeam], [HomeGoals], [AwayGoals]) AS Result" & _
"FROM [" & [season] & "]" & _
"GROUP BY [Date], [HomeTeam], [AwayTeam], [HomeGoals], [AwayGoals], Result([HomeTeam], [AwayTeam], [HomeGoals], [AwayGoals])" & _
"HAVING ((([" & [season] & "].HomeTeam) = [Forms]![frmClubProfile]![comboTeam])) Or ((([" & [season] & "].AwayTeam) = [Forms]![frmClubProfile]![comboTeam]))" & _
"ORDER BY [Date];"

Debug.Print strSQL

Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("qrySeason", strSQL)

DoCmd.OpenQuery "qrySeason"

End Sub
```

**Function:**

```
Public Function Result(ByRef HomeTeam As String, ByRef AwayTeam As String, ByRef HomeGoals As Integer, ByRef AwayGoals As Integer) As String

    team = [Forms]![frmClubProfile]![comboTeam]

    If team = HomeTeam And HomeGoals > AwayGoals Then
        result = "Home Win"
    End If
    If team = HomeTeam And HomeGoals = AwayGoals Then
        result = "Home Draw"
    End If
    If team = HomeTeam And HomeGoals < AwayGoals Then
        result = "Home Lost"
    End If
    If team = AwayTeam And HomeGoals < AwayGoals Then
        result = "Away Win"
    End If
    If team = AwayTeam And HomeGoals = AwayGoals Then
        result = "Away Draw"
    End If
    If team = AwayTeam And HomeGoals > AwayGoals Then
        result = "Away Lost"
    End If
End Function
```

Why does this work in Access but not in VBA?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to expand your form values inside of the string before it is evaluated:

```
"SELECT [Date], [HomeTeam], [AwayTeam], [HomeGoals], [AwayGoals], Result([HomeTeam], [AwayTeam], [HomeGoals], [AwayGoals]) AS Result" & _
"FROM [" & [season] & "]" & _
"GROUP BY [Date], [HomeTeam], [AwayTeam], [HomeGoals], [AwayGoals], Result([HomeTeam], [AwayTeam], [HomeGoals], [AwayGoals])" & _
"HAVING ((([" & [season] & "].HomeTeam) = '" & [Forms]![frmClubProfile]![comboTeam] & "'")) Or ((([" & [season] & "].AwayTeam) = '" & [Forms]![frmClubProfile]![comboTeam] & "'))" & _
"ORDER BY [Date];"
```

Value being expanded:

```
[Forms]![frmClubProfile]![comboTeam]
```

Assuming comboTeam is a string, if it is numeric, skip the single quotes.